# Treat shebang as a comment

Tags: syntax-highlighting, syntax-table

I am trying to get `js-mode` to highlight a "shebang" (`#!/usr/bin/env node`) as a comment, but my code is not working. Instead, the entire buffer is colored like a comment. I've read the documentation for `modify-syntax-entry` carefully but am still not getting anywhere.

I have tried these calls and several similar combinations, but without success:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?# "< 1" js-mode-syntax-table)
(modify-syntax-entry ?! "< 2" js-mode-syntax-table)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```lisp
(modify-syntax-entry ?# ". 1" js-mode-syntax-table)
(modify-syntax-entry ?! ". 2b" js-mode-syntax-table)
```

[Reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Flags.html)

Comment: This worked! Out of curiosity, what makes this correct and my attempt not?

Comment: @Jackson Technically, the only thing you were missing is the `b` in the second line.  The problem was that your comment had a beginning, but no ending.  This solution works because the newline character is already set up in `js-mode-syntax-table` to be a comment end character *for comments of type b*.